# Webdriver.IO: How do I run a specific 'it' statement in Jasmine using WDIO

Tags: jasmine, automated-tests, webdriver-io, wdio-jasmine

I am trying to pull out a smoke suite from my regression suite written using the Jasmine framework (`wdio-jasmine-framework`).

Is it possible to just add a tag on specific testcases in Jasmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly from my Jasmine/Mocha days, there were several ways to achieve this. I'll detail a few, but I'm sure there might be some others too. Use the one that's best for you. 


**1.** Use the `it.skip()` statement inside *a conditional operator expression* to define the state of a test-case (e.g: *in the case of a `smokeRun`, skip the non-smoke tests using: `(smokeRun ? it.skip : it)('not a smoke test', () => { // > do smth here < });`*).

Here is an extended example:

```
// Reading the smokeRun state from a system variable:
const smokeRun = (process.env.SMOKE ? true : false);

describe('checkboxes testsuite', function () {

    // > this IS a smoke test! < //
    it('#smoketest: checkboxes page should open successfully', () => {
        CheckboxPage.open();
        // I am a mock test... 
        // I do absolutely nothing!
    });

    // > this IS NOT a smoke test! < //
    (smokeRun ? it.skip : it)('checkbox 2 should be enabled', () => {
        CheckboxPage.open();
        expect(CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(false);
        expect(CheckboxPage.lastCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(true);
    });

    // > this IS NOT a smoke test! < //
    (smokeRun ? it.skip : it)('checkbox 1 should be enabled after clicking on it', () => {
        CheckboxPage.open();
        expect(CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(false);
        CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.click();
        expect(CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

---

**2.** Use `it.only()` to achieve *mainly* the same effect, the difference being the test-case refactor workload. I'll summarize these ideas as:

- if you have more **smoke tests** than *non-smoke tests*, use the  `it.skip()` approach;
- if you have more **non-smoke tests** than *smoke tests*, use the `it.only()` approach;

You can read more about `pending-tests` [here](https://mochajs.org/#pending-tests).

---

**3.** Use the *runtime skip* (`.skip()`) in conjunction with some nested `describe` statements.

It should look something like this:

```
// Reading the smokeRun state from a system variable:
const smokeRun = (process.env.SMOKE ? true : false);

describe('checkboxes testsuite', function () {

    // > this IS a smoke test! < //
    it('#smoketest: checkboxes page should open successfully', function () {
        CheckboxPage.open();
        // I am a mock test... 
        // I do absolutely nothing!
    });

    describe('non-smoke tests go here', function () {
        before(function() {
            if (smokeRun) {
                this.skip();
            }
        });
        // > this IS NOT a smoke test! < //
        it('checkbox 2 should be enabled', function () {
            CheckboxPage.open();
            expect(CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(false);
            expect(CheckboxPage.lastCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(true);
        });
        // > this IS NOT a smoke test! < //
        it('checkbox 1 should be enabled after clicking on it', function () {
            CheckboxPage.open();
            expect(CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(false);
            CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.click();
            expect(CheckboxPage.firstCheckbox.isSelected()).toEqual(true);
        });
    });
});
```

---

***!Note:*** These are working examples! I tested them using WebdriverIO's recommended [Jasmine Boilerplace](https://github.com/webdriverio/jasmine-boilerplate) project.

***!Obs:*** There multiple ways to filter Jasmine tests, unfortunately only at a test-file(*testsuite*) level (e.g: *using `grep` piped statements, or the built-in WDIO `specs` & `exclude` attributes*).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the iamdanchiv's answer, with WebdriverIO ~7+ & Jasmine ~3.7+ (maybe with older versions too) you can add any **text tag** to your its and describes, and filter the specs to run by it.

A working package.json script is using the **Jasmine's grep**:

```
"smoketest": "wdio run wdio.local.conf.js --suite=temp --jasmineOpts.grep=_smoke"
```

where:

`--suite=temp` is defined in the wdio.local.conf.js suites and runs only those spec files,

`--jasmineOpts.grep=_smoke` finds '_smoke' part in the test (`it`) titles AND `describe` titles inside the above spec files and runs only them.

This would run the full describe

```
describe(`Suite 1 _smoke any other text`, () => {
   it('Test 1-1', async () => {});
   it('Test 1-2', async () => {});
});
```

and tests from another describe(s) like:

```
it('Test 2-1 _smoke is for smoke runs', async () => {});
```

Non-matching tests (its) are skipped.

`_smoke` can be any other text tag you add to the titles.

P.S.: I could not make multiple tags work together, but this is enough to select only smoke tests.